# Angular JS how to retrieve Object ID and other properties when using with Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my code
Here um rendering sequence of Images as follows

```
 <span data-ng-repeat="img in vehilceimages" style="position: relative">
                                                <span style="position: absolute; top: -42px; right: 2px; z-index: 100;" data-ng-click="DeleteImageProperties(img.vehicleId, img.vehiclePhotoId, img.fileName)">&times;</span>
                                                <img data-ng-src="{{folderUrl}}{{img.filePath}}" alt="{{img.vehicleId}}" style="width:10%" />

                                            </span>
```

and um applying the Sortable property in a JS as follows
                var startAt = 0;
                var stopsAt = 0;
                $("#sortable").sortable({
                    cursor: "move",
                    start: function (event, ui) {

```
                    startAt = ui.item.index();

                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {

                    stopsAt = ui.item.index();

                }
            });
            $("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

Sorting happens fine , but I need to retrieve the img object and all of its properties inside  the sorting stop event . I am quite new to Angular and how may I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any DOM manipulation in angular Js should be done from directive. Also that plugin should be really lie inside the directive only so that we need not use of jquery selector here, element will return current DOM where the directive is placed. & then we can easily apply `sortable` on that element.

For getting vehicle information where sortable stop, that can easily you can find inside stop variable, and the second parameter of stop function `ui` that will give you the `item` where it stopped by doing `ui.item`. From that item object you could easily get photo `filePath`, If you want to store that in scope variable then you need to run digest cycle manually to update bindings of the scope, becuase AnglularJs don't run digest cycle when any code run outside angular context like events, plugin events, etc.

**Markup**

```
<div id="sortable" sortable></div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('sortable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.sortable({
                cursor: "move",
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    startAt = ui.item.index();
                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    scope.stoppedItem = ui.item; //this will put in controller stoppedItem variable
                    //or you could simply use ui.item to find out vehicleId
                    scope.$apply(); //run digest cycle here
                    stopsAt = ui.item.index();
                }
            });
            element.disableSelection();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you , how do we access properties like img.vehicleId or img in ng-repeat?

Comment: @SansaKirov I believe ui.item will contain those alll, otherwise do take `ui.item.vehicleId` & then do ` $filter` on `vehilceimages` on basis of vehicalId will give you that item

Comment: seems ui.item does not have those attributes

Comment: could you create a fiddle/plunkr so that I could help you further